# Evaluate the Jacobi Symbol $\frac{1111}{8193}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Evaluate the Jacobi Symbol $\dfrac{1111}{8193}$

The way I approached this was:

$$\frac{1111}{8193} = \frac{416}{1111}=\frac{279}{416}=\frac{137}{249}= \frac{5}{137}=\frac{2}{5}=-1$$

And following the Jacobi properties $$\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{n^2-1}{8}}= -1$$ if $n=3,5.$

Is my computation correct?

Comment: Isn't the Jacobi symbol usually written $\left(\frac{\cdot}{\cdot}\right)$?  Without the parentheses, it's just a fraction, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks correct. As an alternative,
$$\left(\frac{1111}{8193}\right)=\left(\frac{1111}{3}\right)\left(\frac{11}{2731}\right)\left(\frac{101}{2731}\right)=\left(\frac{3}{11}\right)\left(\frac{4}{101}\right)=\left(\frac{11}{3}\right)=-1. $$